# Redirect to cart page after place order success (Magento CE 2.3.1)

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, redirect

I am facing this issue too on Magento CE 2.3.1. I have put the log everywhere since the issue happened.

I can see if using a payment method (currently using Cybersource SecureAcceptance) which will redirect the customer to a payment site and redirect back to Magento store. When it returns and calling successValidator to check isValid(). The session object was another different one so It couldn't get anything about the LastSuccessQuoteId and redirect the customer to cart page as the code described in Magento core.

> if
>   (!$this->_objectManager->get(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\SuccessValidator::class)->isValid())
>   {
>       return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart'); }

Anyone using the same payment method or same kind of payment method facing this issue and resolve it yet?

Comment: Did you get this fixed ?